# How to remove the file path text besides the filename in the explorer sidebar of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VS code explorer, the filename is written along with the complete file path just besides it. How can I remove the file path and just keep the filename to appear in the explorer. Also, is there a way to increase the padding between the file names in the explorer as everything looks extremely small and cluttered.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot which position you mean exactly? In my explorer there are only filenames listet ...

Comment: I have edited my question to include the  screenshot. Have a look.

Comment: Ah, okay then. Well, this is always the case if there's no workspace folder opened. If you open (or create) a workspace folder, then the file name is displayed only. To increase the padding you could change `"window.zoomLevel": 1` for example to `1.2` (`1` is the default). You'll then probably want to adjust `"editor.fontSize"` as well, because increasing `"window.zoomLevel"` of course will affect the displayed fontsize.